# Wordpress with application load balancer resulting in 301 redirect

Tags: wordpress

I have an application load balancer with listener on port 8080. Requests on this listener are forwarded to a target group which has wordpress containers registered on port 80.

Container is launched using ECS (fargate) and has the below container port definition

```
    PortMappings:
        - ContainerPort: 80
          Protocol: tcp
```

With above configuration requests to ALB URL on port 8080 (http://ALBURL:8080) are resulting in a redirect to (http://ALBURL). If I change the listener port to 80, it works fine.

Is there a wordpress configuration I need to change to use ALB listener on 8080?

Comment: This fixed the issue - https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/135343/wordpress-redirecting-connections-on-port-8080-to-80

Answer (score 0):

This fixed the issue - https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/135343/wordpress-redirecting-connections-on-port-8080-to-80

I had to modify the function.php file in the current theme.